# Object scrollable is not working in grails 3 / javascript

Tags: javascript, grails

I am using the below script in my application which throws the error in grails 3.2.8 , but works perfectly fine in grails 1.3.7.

Javascript :

```
$(function() {
$("div.scrollable").scrollable({
vertical:true,
size: 1
}).mousewheel();
});
```

Error: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'scrollable'

Please help me in sorting out the issue

Thanks
Pooja

Comment: Check the source, do you still have a div with class scrollable after upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Client side code has nothing to do with your Grails version. Sounds like you're missing a script to me.

Comment: thanks a lot.... But the same script works perfectly fine in other version of grails

Comment: In version 3 Grails doesn't use a context root like it did in 1.x. Are your script includes trying to find a script with a path that contains an old context root?

Comment: thanks again for replying, Todd. I am not using any script as u have mentioned

Comment: Yes you are. Scrollable is not a native functionality. Sounds like you're using jQuery UI.